# Facebook Open Graph: Approving actions while in debug mode

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, facebook-test-users

I'm developing a facebook canvas application (iframe) and I'm using the Open Graph API to post user actions.

When I submit my action to facebook's team approval, they reply with:

> We are unable to test this action due to an error within your app.
>   Please make sure that your action functions correctly by testing with
>   the Auth Dialog Preview User and re-submit.

Here's the thing. I realised that **only** when I test the application with an app generated test user, I get an error when trying to post open graph action, probably what happend to facebook's tester:

> OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your
>   request later.

Now, when I take my application **out of Sandbox** mode, everything works perfectly, even for test users.

From this I understand that in order to approve my actions with facebook I need to put it out of sandbox mode, which I really prefer not to in this point.

Any tips? did someone faced this issue too? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at a catch 22 if you prefer not to release it from sandbox yet want the actions approved for the public.

Ensure that your application is fully functional under your developer account as well as Testers (who can use the app under Sandbox) before sending for approval then disable Sandbox. Disabling sandbox and sending the action to Facebook is you telling Facebook that your application is ready for review and is no longer in the testing/sandbox stage of development.

[image: Testers for Sandbox]

If you need to re-enable Sandbox after approval, I don't think anything prevents you. I don't believe Facebook will remove the approval, at least, that's my assumption.

Comment: Hope that you're right. My app is fully functional and the only reason I didn't want it out of sandbox mode is only because I don't want the app to be exposed (yet)

Comment: But please tell me, was I right? do I MUST take it out of sandbox in order to make it testable by facebook?

Comment: @GalV yes you must disable sandbox mode for Facebook

Comment: FYI: I just got an action approved while in sandbox mode.

Comment: @GalV Oh, then how did you test your test user in sandbox?

Comment: I didn't, I took it out of sandbox for a moment for testing, and put it back in after. Already 2 actions being approved while in sandbox mode, thats for sure man. thanks for the great advice!